# How to set the operation name in Swagger using Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a WebAPI with an action like "MyActionName" 
The route is set to something like `Books\Read`.

I have XML Comments on and Swashbuckle config'd to generate the SwaggerUI help page.

The actions are listed correctly in Swagger UI, showing `Books\Read` as the name of the operation (for example).

However, codegen based on the Swagger.json results in actions named like "MyActionName", the original name in the C# code.

How can I set the operation name to something else, more like the route (e.g.: `BooksRead`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an Operation Filter like the one below:

```
public class CustomOperationFilter: IOperationFilter
    {        
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {            
            if (operation != null)
            {
                operation.operationId = "OperationName"; // Give whatever name that is required
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, in the swagger config file attach the operation filter:

```
c.OperationFilter<CustomOperationFilter>();
```